# Automatic pivot table query without state case condition

Tags: mysql, sql

Please Help me in merging two mysql queries, since I do not have enough skill in sql programming.

I think this is different with pivoting table in [MySQL pivot table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table) because in that case we still have to state the case statement manually ex : `WHEN DATE_FORMAT(t.mulai, '%Y-%m-%d') = '2014-01-01'` , `WHEN DATE_FORMAT(t.mulai, '%Y-%m-%d') = '2014-07-01'` this is something that I have done.

With the first query, I need to state the condition manually every time new 'mulai' data inserted, for example if a new 'mulai' data 2016-01-01 inserted, I have to add new CASE like this `WHEN DATE_FORMAT(t.mulai, '%Y-%m-%d') = '2016-01-01'` in First query.

**First query :**

```
SELECT
  nip,
  nama,
  DATE_FORMAT(t.tgl_grade_terakhir, '%d-%m-%Y') AS tgl_grade_terakhir,
  (CASE
    WHEN DATE_FORMAT(t.mulai, '%Y-%m-%d') = '2012-01-01' THEN t.nilaitalenta
    ELSE NULL
  END) AS sem1_2012,
  (CASE
    WHEN DATE_FORMAT(t.mulai, '%Y-%m-%d') = '2012-07-01' THEN t.nilaitalenta
    ELSE NULL
  END) AS sem2_2012,
  (CASE
    WHEN DATE_FORMAT(t.mulai, '%Y-%m-%d') = '2013-01-01' THEN t.nilaitalenta
    ELSE NULL
  END) AS sem1_2013,
  (CASE
    WHEN DATE_FORMAT(t.mulai, '%Y-%m-%d') = '2013-07-01' THEN t.nilaitalenta
    ELSE NULL
  END) AS sem2_2013,
  (CASE
    WHEN DATE_FORMAT(t.mulai, '%Y-%m-%d') = '2014-01-01' THEN t.nilaitalenta
    ELSE NULL
  END) AS sem1_2014,
  (CASE
    WHEN DATE_FORMAT(t.mulai, '%Y-%m-%d') = '2014-07-01' THEN t.nilaitalenta
    ELSE NULL
  END) AS sem2_2014,
  (CASE
    WHEN DATE_FORMAT(t.mulai, '%Y-%m-%d') = '2015-01-01' THEN t.nilaitalenta
    ELSE NULL
  END) AS sem1_2015
FROM (SELECT
  nama,
  mulai,
  tgl_grade_terakhir,
  talenta AS nilaitalenta,
  nip
FROM history_talenta) AS t
```

I hope that I can do an automation in case statement with this query, but I don't have any idea about the implementation.

```
SELECT DISTINCT (
mulai
)
FROM history_talenta
WHERE mulai <> '0000-00-00'
ORDER BY mulai ASC
```

which return result like this :

[image]

Comment: To do a dynamic pivot in MySQL, you need to use a stored procedure that generates dynamic SQL with `PREPARE`.

Comment: That is something that I don't know how to implement, I hope you can give me an example ?

Comment: I gave you a link to another question that has examples.

Comment: Can you remove the duplicate mark ?

Comment: Why should I do that? Doesn't the other question have the answer to your question?

Comment: [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26297463/1491895) shows how to create dynamic SQL to solve your problem.